# Qt 5.10.0, Mingw-w64, opencv4.1.0 cannot enter debug mode

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv

I built 64-bit Qt and opencv in Win10, added libs and compiled it with no error. The 64-bit Qt ran successfully, But when I debug a program with opencv contents such as

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("xxx");
    cv::imshow("title", mat);
}
```

The debugging finished directly with no window created. However, the .exe file ran successfully, and the image was showed. I found that there was no .pdb file in the opencv folder. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are your build options?

Comment: Do you mean building Qt or the project?

Comment: When you build your application.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I don't know why, but after I rebooted the pc, the debugging ran successfully...